# Cascading dropdown list in edit page using ASP.NET Core

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

I'm having trouble displaying the `CityId` and `StateId` value from the database to the city and state drop down list based on the selected `Airport` that I wish to edit.

I want the city and and state dropdowns to be selected in edit page based on the `StatesId` and `CitiesId` fetched from database.

This is my jQuery code:

```
$(Document).ready(function () {
    $('#state').attr('disabled', true);
    $('#city').attr('disabled', true);
    LoadStates();

    $('#state').change(function () {
        var statesId = $(this).val();
        if (statesId > 0) {
            LoadCities(statesId)
        }
        else {
            alert("Please select a state!");
            $('#city').empty();
            $('#city').attr('disabled', true);
            $('#city').append('<option>---Select a City---</option>');
        }
    })
});

function LoadStates() {
    $('#state').empty();

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Airports/GetStates',
        success: function (response) {
            if (response != null && response != undefined && response.length > 0) {
                $('#state').attr('disabled', false);
                $('#state').append('<option>---Select a State---</option>');
                $('#city').append('<option>---Select a City---</option>');
                $.each(response, function (i, data) {
                    $('#state').append('<option value='+data.id+'>'+data.name +'</option>')
                });

            }
            else {
                $('#state').attr('disabled', false);
                $('#city').attr('disabled', false);
                $('#state').append('<option>---State Not Available---</option>');
                $('#city').append('<option>---City Not Available---</option>');
            }
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
}

function LoadCities(statesId) {
    $('#city').empty();

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Airports/GetCities?Id=' + statesId,
        success: function (response) {
            if (response != null && response != undefined && response.length > 0) {
                $('#city').attr('disabled', false);
                $('#city').append('<option>---Select a City---</option>');
                $.each(response, function (i, data) {
                    $('#city').append('<option value=' + data.id + '>' + data.name + '</option>')
                });

            }
            else {
                $('#city').attr('disabled', false);
                $('#city').append('<option>---City Not Available---</option>');
            }
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
}
```

My controller

```
public JsonResult GetStates()
{
    var states = _context.states.OrderBy(x => x.Name).OrderBy(x => x.Id).ToList();
    return new JsonResult(states);
}

public JsonResult GetCities(int id)
{
    var city = _context.cities.Where(x => x.StatesId == id).OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
    return new JsonResult(city);
}
```

My edit view

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label asp-for="StatesId" class="col-lg-4 col-form-label">
       State
       <span class="text-danger">*</span>
    </label>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <select asp-for="StatesId" id="state" class="js-example-basic-single" name="StatesId"></select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
    <label asp-for="CitiesId" class="col-lg-4 col-form-label">
       City
       <span class="text-danger">*</span>
    </label>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <select asp-for="CitiesId" id="city" class="js-example-basic-single" name="CitiesId"></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the issue do you meet? From your code, There are two drop down lists in your view, The first one is for state and the second one is for city, When user select a state in the first drop down list, The second drop down list will only show the cities which belong to the state you select, Do you want to achieve it? I test your code and every thing goes well, So i am not sure what's the issue you meet.

Comment: the cascading dropdown works well, the problem is for example when i create an item and choose the state as USA and City as New York, when i go to the edit page the dropdown State should be selected as USA and City dropdown should be selected as New York.
Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure if i can get your point, Do you mean you have a create page and you can create an item in that page, After you create an item, When you edit this item in edit page, The drop down lists should be selected as what you select in create page?

Comment: Yes exactly thats what i mean.

Comment: In my opinion, in your http get edit action, You can receive the item's id as parameter, When user click edit button, it will pass the selected item's id into edit action, you can select sate and city via this id from and set default options in dropdown list.